# How to send github activity feed graph from your organisational account to your personal github account?

Tags: github

As my organizational GitHub account is `xyz@github.com` and I have made a lot of contributions to that, and I really like the green dots, is there any way I can send the activity feed to my personal GitHub account from email id (`abc@github.com`)?

I just want to send these green dots to my personal email :(

[feed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D323J.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't transfer activity from one account to another like that.  The contribution graph lists all activity created by your account and only your account.

The only way you'd be able to transfer activity is if you removed the email address specified in the commits made by your organizational account and associated it with your personal account.  Because GitHub uses the email address in the commits to attribute the commits to an account, that would make those commits be associated with your personal account.

However, this doesn't transfer activity other than commits from one account to another.  This is intentionally not transferable because doing so can lead to misattribution and abuse.

I should point out that while the contribution graph is a neat feature, it's not a measure of your self-worth or your competence as a developer and so you shouldn't worry about how densely it's populated.